# Is there a MDI/SDI/TDI Framework available for Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, frameworks, mdi

I am converting an older MDI (Multiple Document Interface in Windows-speak, I don't know what it is called in Java) to Multiple SDI (Single Document interface). It's really "one top window with a menu, owning multiple separate JFrames, each containing their own logic and display". I also plan to have Open/Save workspace. MVC is used as the general architecture.

I have started, and the main idea is to create a bunch of JFrame-derived windows which I keep track of in a Window menu. Models and Controllers of course, but its the View/JFrame that is the main problem. I have already lost myself in a myriad of Action handlers and Window Listeners....

Then it hit me, "this can't be the first time someone writes this". A quick search on Google and SO lead me nowhere. But surely there must exist a framework which does this already? (Preferably in a Model-View-Controller design)

When all I want is to create Models and Controllers, and then implement only the thing that is special for each window/JFrame. The rest (Window management, workspace etc) should be preety standard.

I guess I'm looking for something similar to the App-Wizards/Code-generators in DevStudio.

Does such a framework exist, or am I bound to make one myself?

Answer (score 2):

***I know this question is old, just leting here my findings since i had this similar question a while ago.***

There is really not such framework/utility out-of-the box, swing really only provides UI controls and components, you have to code youself data binging and validation, also its up to you to handle MDI ( using JInterfalFrames) or SDI (Using a single JFrame and a bunch of jpanels).

As you mentioned, swing does not makes implementing MVC *easily*, due to all code that may end up inside the *Listeners and *Adapters.

You can make a POC to try out varios swing data-binding frameworks like [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/download/presentations/binding.pdf) or [Project Mogwai](http://mogwai.sourceforge.net/databinding.html), disclamer: haven't used neither.

Optionally if the project allows it, you could try alternative UI frameworks for java like [Apache Pivot](https://pivot.apache.org/) or [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) wich does a better job at separating ui from behaivor.

Sorry for my bad english.